# How to access the value attribute of a progress tag from backend code

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I'm trying to make a progress bar to display during some "modifying" we are doing to 200,000+ rows from an excel document. I just wanted to try something simple, but I can't seem to get the value attribute from the progress tag.

For example if I had something simple like:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlPercent" runat="server">
    <progress id="progressPercent" runat="server"></progress>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And:

```
public static void CleanExcelSheet()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
    {
        ... // Clean whatever
        progressPercent.Value = i / rows.Count;
        upnlPercent.Update();
    }
}
```

Is anyone aware of a simple way I could handle something like this?  I'm open to other suggestions also if this doesn't really seem like a viable solution.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you would want to do, is store the percent in a session var `Session["percent"]`, and set a `Load` handler to your update panel where you would update the progress from the session var.

on client side, you would use javascript to make the update panel post back and update each certain amount of miliseconds.

an important thing to remember, is to run your cleaning function on a separate thread so it would not block your app, and allow the app to listen to post backs from the update panel.

here is an example of how to do it:

**aspx:**

this is our update panel with an element inside which we will update

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" OnLoad="UpdatePanel1_Load">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <label id="Label_For_Server_Time" runat="server"></label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Click Me" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

**in your aspx header, add the following code:**

this code calls the built-in asp.net postback function on the update panel, it will fire the `Load` handler of the update panel without refreshing the whole page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        setInterval("__doPostBack('<%=UpdatePanel1.ClientID%>', '');", 1000);
    }
</script>
```

**code behind:**

this is the load handler for the update panel, it fires everytime the panel is posting back from the aspx page, we are checking if the session var exists, and setting the label text:

```
protected void UpdatePanel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["percent"] != null)
    {
        Label_For_Server_Time.InnerText = Session["percent"].ToString();
    }
}
```

this is your function, we are running it on a separate thread to not block the app and setting the session var accordingly.

```
public void CleanExcelSheet()
{
    new Thread(delegate()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        {
            //... your cleaning here

            float _f = (float)i / 100000000;
            Session["percent"] = _f;
        }
    }).Start();
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CleanExcelSheet();
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks a bunch for the extensive response.  This was very very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

On the server side, the type of `progressPercent` is `HtmlGenericControl`, which allows you to get/set properties like this:

```
progressPercent.Attributes["value"] = (i / rows.Count).ToString();
```

Or if the attribute is not already present, you may have to do the following:

```
progressPercent.Attributes.Add("value", (i / rows.Count).ToString());
```